# Updating $(this) but the span within it

Tags: jquery, text

I'm trying to update the `<span>` within an anchor depending on whether you click or not. If you click it and the slide is open, it's 'navigateup', if it's not active, it's 'navigatedown'.

I have this working if it's the whole anchor that needs changing, but I just need to change the span. Also, I could write a separate script for it, but I thought it would be best to include it within the jQuery that already exists.

Any ideas?

I have this HTML:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-29 parent"><a href="#">Clinical/Laboratory<span class="ss-icon navigation-drop-icon">navigatedown</span></a></li>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$(".sub-navigation li.parent > a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   $(this).text($(this).text() == 'navigateup' ? 'navigatedown' : 'navigateup');
   $(this).closest('.parent').find("> .children").slideToggle(400);
});
```

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you could provide the span as a selector for the text and then use `this` as the context to look within, something like this:

```
 $("span", this).text($("span", this).text() == 'navigateup' ? 'navigatedown' : 'navigateup');
```

The jQuery function allow you to pass a second parameter, which is the context to look within when using your selector. The span selector will only match span-elements within the clicked element in this case.

According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), the context can be:

> A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

I think jQuery uses the `.find()` method behind the scenes, so in your case the above example is just a shorthand for `$(this).find("span")`

Comment: This is perfect. I wasn't aware of the second parameter opportunity. Great stuff. Thanks again. Will mark as answer when it allows.

Comment: So, I could have done: $(this).find('span').text($(this).find('span').text() == 'navigateup' ? 'navigatedown' : 'navigateup');

Comment: @Richard Yes exactly, but in my opinion, that is a bit harder to read than using the context parameter of the jQuery function.